# Global iteration path for different projects on TFS

Tags: tfs, iteration, collaboration

In our company there are a lot of projects that are connected by resources (people). So, people from one project works in onother one too. We are going to create Global Iteration (Iteration Path) that to  assign items on it from different projects that to see all planned work in one common backlog.

But as far as I know it is not possible to do that for different projects. 
Moreover, combining two projects is not a solution for me. Any ideas?

PS: I know the advantages and disadvantages of Single project (see [topic](http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx)) but it is not my case.

Comment: All I can think of is a custom field using a Global List of values and then query on that instead (we do that and only have 1 TP that's because >1 team can work on a project and each team has its own iterations)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but with queries I already could select WI's that are defined on Iterations from other projects without any additional custom fields. But in that case native burndowns and reports on dashboard and other native features will not work, so will not take into account the elements from different projects. Moreover, I like just say: show me all elements assigned on @CurrentIteration, Instead I need all time change my query for each sprint by adding addition iteration from another project.

Comment: I don't think TFS will provide anything native for this, you could do your burndowns etc. with TFS's SSRS integration that works across Team Projects and even Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't show work items from multiple Team Projects on a single Kanban board in TFS.

As a workaround, you can either create your own query as @DaveShaw mentioned, or use one Team Project with multiple Teams and use features from Agile Portfolio Management. See https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/portfolio-management